# Screenshot of selected area with shadow?

Tags: macos, keyboard, screen-capture

Is it even possible?
I understand it's possible for a window, when you press space after <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>.
I want shadow on my selected area screenshot, so it doesn't blend with the rest of the page/email/text/etc?

This page seems to be on the topic but still doesn't have an answer I'm looking for.
http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the built-in functionality, but there's a bunch of tools out there that do this kind of stuff, including the cursor in the screenshot, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Grab** doesn't generate the shadow when a Window is copied, it copies the shadow that the OS has already applied to each window.

However, If you want to apply a shadow to your screen shots it can be done with extra steps using other applications.

If you have **Keynote** or **Pages** installed, you can replicate it with a few steps.

- Open **Keynote** or **Pages** (instructions same after this point)
- Select a template.  The background does not matter but white shows your work better
- Drag or paste in your screenshot.  **Note:** Using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> you can send your screenshot directly to the clipboard.
- Apply a drop shadow to your image
- Select and copy just the image and paste it into your email or desired location.

See images below:

Original Screenshot:

[image: Grab]

Keynote modification:

[image: Keynote]

Result:

[image: Result]